# aws-amplify serializes body data by default, how to prevent it and send string instead of JSON

Tags: aws-amplify, rest

I'm using API class from 'aws-amplify' library that has rest api methods (get, post, put, detele).
And as far as I see these methods serialize body under the hood (you don't need to write body: JSON.stringify(data)). But if there is some backend method, that expects to see just string, not JSON as body data, how can I prevent aws-amplify from serializing body data by default.
Thank you.